# Change specific extension with * as name keeping name using php

Tags: php

So some reason server changes random (?) .php files to .ph.
Need to rename any .ph file to .php 
Tried about every rename and rename extension code I found on stackflow. 
Nothing has worked so far. 
No root access (shared) 
working directory will be /

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you just trying to rename all `*.ph` files to `*.php`? Also, something is *very* wrong with your server if this is "randomly" happening; it sounds like you're hacked.

Comment: does renaming of file extension make any difference ? does your application still work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :(Tested in localhost)

```
if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
unlink('test.ph');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to rename all the .ph files in the current directory to .php, you can try this:

```
<?php
  $old_extension = '.ph';
  $new_extension = '.php';

  $files = glob("*$old_extension");

  foreach($files as $file){
    $filename = pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    rename($file,$filename . $new_extension);
  }
?>
```

**A word of caution:** the script will rename the existing files in the current directory without warning.

I highly advise running the above script in a development environment or within a Test directory beforehand so you know what to expect.

Best-